# Resizing the list's scrollbars in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, scrollbar, customization, listctrl

I use wx.ListCtrl
when add listitem, listctrl create scrollbar on Rigth or bottom

I want custom scrollbar of listctrl 
or hide scrollbar when appear
what should i do?

Comment: I don't think that you can. How do you propose to be able to see or select an item beyond the bounds of the listctrl window, if you don't have a scrollbar?

Comment: I understand your comment.
Is there a way to change the size of the scrollbars created in the list?